# Почему слайдер bootstrap перекрывает навигационную панель?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Слайдер, подключенный с помощью bootstrap, перекрывает выпадающий список навигации из бургера. Position: absolute везде снят. На первом скриншоте - сайт с нормальным размером страницы; здесь видны пять навигационных ссылок: "про нас", и т.д.. На втором - эта же страница шириной менее 992px; здесь видно, что у бургер-меню    хорошо отображается лишь три ссылки: остальные перекрыты слайдером снизу.
Пожалуйста, помогите сделать так, чтобы этот выпадающий список при открытии толкал слайдер вниз[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: проверь z-index и position. Если не сработает, навесь на родителя position:relative, z-index: 10. Если не сработает, то на родителя родителя и так далее.

Comment: Большое спасибо, VladykoD! Не могу из-за маленькой репутации как-то отметить ваш ответ.

Comment: @VladykoD спасибо!